# Bash. How to get multiline text between tags

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to get text in my file between two tags. But if script finds opening tag and do not finds closing tag then it prints file from opening tag to the file's end.

For example text is:

```
aaa
TAG1
some right text
TAG2
some text2
TAG1
some text3
some text4
```

and script like this:

```
awk "/TAG1/,/TAG2/"
```

or

```
sed -n "/TAG1/,/TAG2/p"
```

than output will be:

```
some right text
some text3
some text4
```

but I need this:

```
some right text
```

Comment: Means you don't want text in tag that does not closed.

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never use range expressions as they make tirivial tasks slightly briefer but then need a complete rewrite to avoid duplicate conditions when things get even slightly more interesting, as in your case. Always use a flag instead:

```
$ awk 'f{ if (/TAG2/){printf "%s", buf; f=0; buf=""} else buf = buf $0 ORS}; /TAG1/{f=1}' file
some right text
```

Comment: I added this great approach into my set of solutions of [How to select lines between two patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/1983854). I hope you don't mind!